# Why hadn't we defined the $p$-norm of matrices similar as that of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

We have defined the induced norm
$$\|A\|_p=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|_p,$$
but why not
$$\|A\|_p=\left(\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^p\right)^{\frac1p}=\|\mathrm{vec}(A)\|_p$$?

Comment: What you defined is also a norm. There are many different norms you can define on a vector space. It's just that the induced norms have very good properties, so many times it is easier to work with them.

Comment: you can write any vector norm   on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$  and apply it to square matrices.  This will usually fail  the "induced" part. For example, the identity matrix always has induced norm $1$  Furthermore,  an induced norm $\phi$ has   $\phi(AB) \leq \phi(A) \phi(B) .$   This will take more work to check but typically fails as well.

Comment: In the induced norm, you miss a $p$ on the right. What is vec(A)?

Comment: square matrices:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Square_matrices  Example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Norms_induced_by_p-norms

Comment: @squid thanks - I've added the $p$. The "vec" denotes the vectorization of a matrix, which converts $A$ to a column vector.

Comment: @Jeremy: thanks. Presumably you have $\|x\|_p=1$ on the right too :-)